# How to make a traingle of characters based on user input

Tags: c

I'm CS newbie, and I'm currently taking an introductory course in C. I need to understand how to print a right triangle of * which base and heigth are given by user input.

Since I don't know how to print a character one more time for every row, I thought I could use a space character before starting a new line. But when I write this code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main ()
{
    char s[80];
    int a, i, j;

    fgets(s, sizeof(s), stdin);
    a = atoi(s);

    if (a == 0) 
        printf("No print\n");
    for (i = a - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        for (j = 1; j <= a - i; j++) {
            printf("*\n");
        } 
        printf("%c", ' ');
    }
    return 0;
}
```

the output is a lot of asterisks (the right number of asterisks I'd like the output to have) and only one last, final space. Is there something I can do to modify my code, or a better way to write it for solving the same problem? (My professor don't want us to use scanf yet).

EDIT: Okay, I changed the braces, thanks a lot. Now the output for 4 is:

```
4
*
 *
*
 *
*
*
 *
*
*
*
```

but I still can't figure out why. Maybe I put the braces in the wrong place?

Comment: Look at http://cpp.forum24.ru/?1-1-0-00000094-000-0-0-1583243331

Comment: Perhaps you should print spaces and newlines *inside* one of the loops?

Comment: Use braces `{}` for the outer for loop.

Comment: What is the expected output for the input `4` for example? Also think about about inputs like `0` and `-1`. What will your program do with those?

Comment: Please don't make rolling changes to the code to show your progress - this isn't an interactive tutorial. Just leave the question the way it is, and change the code you are using.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude thanks a lot. I still have this problem, and I don't know why

Comment: Write down on a piece of paper the exact steps you need to take. Draw the star pattern by hand, thinking about what you actually do.

Comment: @Weather Vane okay, I'm sorry, this is my first question, I won't do that anymore

Comment: @Weather Vane that'd what I did, and on paper I think it works, but when I try to write it it doesn't, so I think I'm doing some logical mistake, but I can't understand which

Comment: You are printing a newline after every star, that can't be what is needed.

Comment: @Weather Vane thanks a lot, I can see it now.

Comment: _"but I still can't figure out why. Maybe I put the braces in the wrong place?"_ - You have still not explained what you expect from your program.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't read the whole explanation, but I read this: you want to create a triangle and you have written source which looks like:

```
for (...
    for (...
        printf("*\n");
    ...
    printf(...) // no \n
```

The `\n` is a newline character and makes sure that, after having written an asterisk, you immediately jump to the next line. Obviously you can't create a triangle like that: you must at least have some characters, next to each other, before going to the next line.

So I would suggest something like:

```
for (...
    for (...
        printf("*");
    ...
    printf(... "\n") // \n present in this statement.
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is correct, just adjust printf statement and newline '\n'
Code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    char s[80];
    int a, i, j;

    fgets(s, sizeof(s), stdin);
    a = atoi(s);

    if (a == 0) 
        printf("No print\n");
    for (i = a - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        for (j = 1; j <= a - i; j++) {
            printf("*");
        } 
        printf(" \n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's an alternative to the core functionality. As is, it's limited to the 20 'stars' of the initialised string. I hope this is educational.

```
char *stars = "********************";
char *tail = stars + strlen( stars) - 1;

int i = 15;
while( i-- )
    printf( "%s\n", tail-- );
```